# How to loop through a vector that corresponds to another vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a column of years from 1981 to 2000 that corresponds to another column of prices for a good. I am trying to make a loop that iterates through only the years from 1990 to 2000 and prints the prices in order that correlates with their year. I have this code so far but I'm not sure why it won't run, any help would be awesome.

```
for x=1:year == 1990:2000
v = find(isfinite(price));
v
end
```

Comment: It won't run because you appear to have just invented some syntax!  Where did you read that `for x=1:year == 1990:2000` was valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input data is something like this where the first column is year and the second column is price

```
data = [1990, 2.50;
        1991, 3.00;
        ...
        2000, 4.00];
```

You can loop through the years in your for loop (Note the syntax and how this compares to the one in your post) and then find the second column where the price corresponds to that year using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/).

```
for year = 1990:2000
    % Grabs column 2 where column 1 is equal to the year
    price = data(data(:,1) == year, 2);
end
```

Even if your data lives in two different data structures you can do something similar (as long as they are the same size).

```
years = [1990, 1991, 1992, ... 2000];
prices = [2.50, 3.00, 3.50, ... 4.00];

for year = 1990:2000
    price = prices(years == year);
end
```

**Edit**

If you are for-loop averse, you can definitly do the same thing without a for loop. The most robust solution is to use [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html).

```
annualPrices = arrayfun(@(x)prices(years == x), years, 'uniform', 0);
```

This will return a cell array where each element is all prices for a given year.

If you're guaranteed to only have one price per year, however, you can omit the `uniform` input and you'll get an array of prices.

```
annualPrices = arrayfun(@(x)prices(years == x), years);
```

One of the benefits is that neither of these approaches requires extra operations (such as sorting) on your data.

Comment: Thanks everyone that's a big help

Comment: @Suever, no need to use a for-loop.

Comment: @NKN I completely agree. I was trying to keep it as straightforward as possible for the user (similar to their initial code) without obfuscating too much. I will add in non-for loop version.

Comment: @NKN That being said, I don't think that an extraneous `sort` operation is better than a for loop especially given MATLAB's JIT compilation.

Comment: @Suever nice update! I think `sort` is implemented in C++ level in MATLAB the same as `arrayfun`, but for-loop can be slower since it is pure MATLAB.

Comment: @NKN Well so I ran some preliminary tests just because I was curious and it appears as though both `arrayfun` and `sort` are actually slower than a straight-up for loop. The reason that I think this is is 1) JIT compilation has gotten *very* good in the last few releases and 2) the for loop is only over the range of dates that you actually want so in this example you're only doing 11 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

**Example 1:**

Let's make a matrix holding your data:

```
M = ones(100,2);  % 1st column for the year and the second column for the prices
M(:,1) = (1951:2050).';
M(:,2) = rand(100,1);
```

A one liner to your question can be as follows:

```
M((M(:,1)<= 2000 & M(:,1) >= 1990),2)
```

**Example 2:**

If you have prices and years in two vectors, first make sure your years are sorted:

```
[sortedYears,Idx] = sort(years);    % sort the years vector
sortedPrices = prices(Idx);         % use the index to sort the prices in the same order
```

Now use the following one liner:

```
sortedPrices((sortedYears<= 2000 & sortedYears >= 1990));
```